# increase log output for SSLPeerUnverifiedException issues

Tags: java, ssl, logging, truststore

I am running into an `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException` in my current project. Even though log level is set to ALL the logs do not show what I would like to know.

> Certificate for <#####.com> doesn't match any of the subject
> alternative names: [.#####.com]
> (org.apache.http.conn.ssl.DefaultHostnameVerifier)

I read that there is a way to enable additional logging for SSL and I lost the source for that.

Is there an environment attribute, or the like, that I could set to get more log entries for SSL?

Comment: See the JSSE Reference Guide, 'debugging utilities'.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Perfect, that is it. Thanks.

Comment: The error message it does show seems fairly clear as to what the problem is: you're asking to connect to example.com but example.com is not one of the subjectAltNames in the server certificate as it must be.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Yeah - we did not know what truststore was in use and there were other confusing things about this message. We solved it after we checked the extended messages.

Answer (score 0):

MarquisofLorne gave the anser in a comment:

> See the JSSE Reference Guide, 'debugging utilities'

[This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Debug) source has the option I was looking for `-Djavax.net.debug=all`.
Less agressive versions are also available there.